# Convert string in to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have a string: "20180830"  which represents 30 august 2018
I want to go to string: "30/08/2018"
So that I can do: DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse("30/08/2018"); and have a DateTime instead of a string,

Tried everything but didn't succeed.
Needs some help.

Comment: Use `var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("20180830", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: `string result = DateTime.ParseExact("20180830", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)-Method to solve your problem. Therefore you need to specify the exact format which would be `yyyyMMdd` in your case. Also the documentation suggests to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

The following code...

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("20180830", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

...should do the trick ;-)